# how do I exclude the height of my div from the height of the HTML element?

Tags: html, css, background

I have my HTML background set up like this:

```
html {
    background: url("main_bg2.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;     
}
```

Which works exactly like I want it to. The background is centered, covers the whole browser window and stays proportional.

However, if I have a lot of content that extends the page height and makes it scroll then my background image expands to include the height of the large div and it ends up zooming in way too much.

Is there a way to exlcude the height of the div from the overall height of the HTML element so that the picture does not get larger as the DIV does?

Sort of like having the div scroll through the browser window without affecting the height of the HTML element?

Comment: Try to make a fiddle or a sample snippet, so we can help you more faster,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend changing the container that you're putting the background in. By definition you're targeting everything on the page by selecting the html element. I would make a container and put all of the elements you want in front of the background in that.

```
<html>
   <div class="page_container">
       <div> Your elements </div>
   </div>
   <div> The other components that are stretching your background </div>
</html>
```

Then you can just do this:

```
.page_container {
    background: url("main_bg2.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What if you use:

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

?

Comment: I think that is what is causing the problem. I have it set to fixed but I read that for IOS devices I need it set to scroll. The problem seems to be only on my ipad.

Comment: Ah gotcha. I think the other guy gave a better answer

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/saLb48vg/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var bodyBG = $('.no-bg').height();

  $('body').css('background-positionY', bodyBG);
});
```

Try this, this not reduces the size, but the position so it takes less size to cover depending on the height of what you want to exclude.